# how to resolve your device isn't compatible with this Version

Tags: android

My app min sdk version is 14, target sdk version is 23, in Samsung Galaxy A3(version 7.0) is showing:

```
your device isn't compatible with this version
```

and previous it is working good, here is my manifest file please, anyone can help me.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.teneno.mobile">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:name="de.blinkt.openvpn.core.Teneno"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/blinkt"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
```

Comment: Your target sdk version is 23 i.e marshmallow and you are testing on Nougat 7.0 i.e 24. Change target version to 24 in build.gradle and make other necessary changes accordingly. Your problem will be solved.

Comment: but in same device previously it is working good , but why it is showing this message, i don't understand.

Comment: what is previous apk target sdk version?

Comment: my previous target sdk version is 23 only

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're only targeting Android TV?

You can try cleaning up your manifest first then removing the unnecessary `uses-feature` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. It should be something like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

<application
    android:name="de.blinkt.openvpn.core.Teneno"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/blinkt"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
```

Comment: Thanks for replay but this is not worked in my case, actually the problem is in Google play console in side Device cat log 's  Samsung A3 device as excluded by Including Samsung A3 device it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's different for everyone, so I'll answer how I fixed when I ran into this issue, I did steps below (not sure whether it was step 1 or 2 that fixed it though).

1.I added:

```
<supports-screens
android:anyDensity="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

2.I removed all the tags that say uses-permission in it. But I only had 2, which were:
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW